# Get date for Saturday two weeks ago

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm currently building a query which needs to show data from Saturday to Friday. For example, running the query today you should get data from 7/24 to 7/30. I’m seeing data from 7/25 to 7/30 and I frankly don’t know how to fix the code below to get Saturday’s data as well.

Here’s what I have:

```
WHERE
InvoiceDate BETWEEN DATEADD(WEEK, -2, DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 5, GETDATE()), 5)) 
AND DATEADD(DAY, -3, DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
```

Preferably, I’d like to keep the similar format rather than parameterizing the query. Unless that’s a better idea of course! I’m also asking this on my phone so I apologize for not including the entire query. However because it is in the where clause, I figured the rest wasn’t needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're leaving out a lot of information so assuming that you are running this query every Monday (as of my reply, today is Monday) and you are just going back to last-last Saturday to last Friday, your WHERE clause can be quite simple:

```
where InvoiceDate between dateadd(day,-9,getdate()) and dateadd(day,-3,getdate())
```

if there are are more criteria or conditions then let us know.

Answer (score 0):

try the following query, just put the date whenever you need

```
SELECT 
case 
    when datepart(weekday, '2021/08/03') >5 
        then DATEADD(DAY, +4, DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, '2021/08/03'), 0))
    else DATEADD(DAY, -9, DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, '2021/08/03'), 0)) 
end AS last_saturday,
case 
    when datepart(weekday, '2021/08/03') >5 
        then DATEADD(DAY, +4, DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, '2021/08/03'), 0))
    else DATEADD(DAY, -3, DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, '2021/08/03'), 0)) 
end AS last_friday;
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize you have an answer already, but this will allow you to use whatever date you want. Using the day of the week to subtract days from today will give you the previous Saturday.  Subtracting 7 from that will give you the Saturday a week ago.

So given that, the below will search the range from the start of a week ago  Saturday until the start of this previous Saturday.  This works with both date and datetime data types.

```
WHERE InvoiceDate >= DATEADD(day, -7 +  DATEPART(dw,GETDATE()) * -1, GETDATE()) 
    AND InvoiceDate < DATEADD(day,  DATEPART(dw,GETDATE()) * -1, GETDATE())
```